# React Native semi-circle partial shadow

Tags: react-native, shadow, react-native-ios

How to draw drop shadow only on the curved parts of a semi-circle Button in React Native, created with the following code base.

```
export default function SemiCircleButton({
  icon,
  style,
  ...props
}: Props): Element<*> {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[styles.semiCircle, style]}
      activeOpacity={0.8}
      {...props}>
      <Image source={icon} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  semiCircle: {
    width: radius / 1.5,
    height: 40,
    borderTopRightRadius: radius,
    borderBottomRightRadius: radius,
    backgroundColor: white,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```